# Set min-buffer threshold for http/network playback

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

In a video player project, I'd like to use LibVLC http streaming from a slow source.

However, I can not get it to stream FIRST, and then continuously download data. The player will always stop in-between.

I'm using vlc-android from GIT.

This is the media player setup code:

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
options.add("--no-sub-autodetect-file");
options.add("--swscale-mode=0");
options.add("--network-caching=60000");

if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
}

libVLC = new LibVLC(options);

mediaPlayer = new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(libVLC);
mediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);

final IVLCVout vout = mediaPlayer.getVLCVout();
vout.setVideoView(videoView);
vout.setSubtitlesView(subtitleView);
vout.addCallback(this);
vout.attachViews();

final Media media = new Media(libVLC, getIntent().getData());
media.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, false);
media.addOption(":network-caching=60000");
media.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
media.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");

mediaPlayer.setMedia(media);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

I was hoping that setting the `:network-caching` on the media object is enough, but it seems to still run out of data the whole time.

How to configure LibVLC so that the stutter is eliminated? Some buffer time is OK.

The stream type is a MOV file served via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

libvlc option try it:

```
ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
options.add("--audio-time-stretch"); // time stretching
options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity
options.add("--no-audio"); // no audio
options.add("--aout=none");
options.add("--no-sub-autodetect-file");
options.add("--swscale-mode=0");
options.add("--network-caching=400");
options.add("--no-drop-late-frames");
options.add("--no-skip-frames");
options.add("--avcodec-skip-frame");
options.add("--avcodec-hw=any");
```

media addOption try it:

```
Media m = new Media(libvlc, Uri.parse(URL));
m.setHWDecoderEnabled(true, true);
m.addOption(":network-caching=5000");
m.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
m.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");
m.addOption(":codec=all");
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
mMediaPlayer.play();
```